# Any software utility available to do USB port sniffing in MAC OSx ?

Tags: macos, usb, sniffer

Is there any handy software utility available to do USB port sniffing on MAC OSx 10.6 and above ? We can do that in Windows with few software utils available as freeware and several licensed versions...

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. See the [help/on-topic] page for details (specifically, the numbered list, item #5).

Comment: I feel this is a question purely related to USB development and debugging on MAC OS X and may not be considered as a spam. If its violating the rules, then I will delete the question here and may seek for help in other forums.

Comment: Since I am new to StackOverflow, I didn't have a chance to go through the posting rules thoroughly. If it violates the posting rule, then I will request the moderator to close/delete this question. No issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are [registered as an Apple developer](https://developer.apple.com/register/index.action), you can download a version of the IOUSBFamily code with logging enabled; it comes with a "USB Prober" application.  That might let you do some of what you want.  I'm not sure Apple provides any code in the standard version of the USB code that lets you get that sort of information from the USB stack.

Comment: But you see, the logging version of IOUSBFamily kext along with UsbProber provides USB requests made and status of those requests but does not provide full packet data information as what we get in softwares running on Windows.

Answer (score -2):

Wireshark is a powerful tool that allows to capture traffic generated by different kinds of devices (Ethernet, USB, raw, etc...).
You can also save USB traffic generated from USB devices.

libpcap releases prior to 1.0 do not include USB support, so install at least libpcap 1.0.0.

Comment: Wireshark supports USB ports on an OS sniffing only if libpcap supports it on that OS, and the *only* OS on which libpcap currently supports USB port sniffing is Linux - *not* OS X.

Comment: Yes that's what I have seen while testing Wireshark on OS X ML. Wireshark captures network packets on OS X, but not USB raw data.

Comment: I would also like an answer to this question. I don't feel its an unreasonable one as its not a case of comparing one solution to another (which invites opinionated responses) but simply of finding any or all solutions which could then be investigated. The answer seems to be that nothing with the required capabilities is available on mac osx.